Setting and accessing object generically in Typescript
Simplified code version at the bottom:
I am trying to solve dynamically accessed and set objects.
I have a type like this:
export type PriceCorrections = {
  main: PriceCorrections;
  services: Record<number,PriceCorrection>;
};

And I have state that is implementing that type:
const initialState: PriceCorrections

Then I have an action that takes keyof PriceCorrections and I try to set the state dynamically, so I do:
state.priceCorrections[action.paylod.data] = initialState[action.paylod.data]

The problem is that both parts of the equation are seen by TypeScript as union of
PriceCorrections | Record<number,PriceCorrection>, so logically it doesn't allow me to set PriceCorrections to Record<number,PriceCorrection> and vice versa, but since the action.paylod.data is the same in both cases, it can't happen, it's always the same key and therefore it works as intended, but TypeScript doesn't/can't see it. Is there a solution to this?
I am forced to do if check for my code with exactly same code, just to remove the error:
if (action.paylod.data === 'services') {
state.priceCorrections[action.paylod.data] = initialState[action.paylod.data]

} else {
state.priceCorrections[action.paylod.data] = initialState[action.paylod.data] 
}

Is there a type safe way to solve this using "typescript": "^4.9.5"?
EDIT here is simplified version of the problem, whcih you can replicate
export type ObjectType = {
  main: boolean;
  services: Record<number, boolean>;
};

let editedState: ObjectType = {
  main: false,
  services: {},
};

let initialState: ObjectType = {
  main: false,
  services: {},
};

const resetStateBroken = (action: keyof ObjectType) => (editedState[action] = initialState[action]);

const resetStateWorks = (action: keyof ObjectType) => {
  if (action === 'services') {
    editedState[action] = initialState[action];
  } else {
    editedState[action] = initialState[action];
  }
};


You're running into ms/TS#32693 and the current approach is to use generics instead of unions, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

Yes, thats perfect! I didnt realize that I can use generics, because it was anonymous function inside Redux. Thank you very much, also added simplified code of the problem down bellow to the question for better clarity.
